# React-grid-layout with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-grid-layout

I add react-grid-layout to my react-hooks projects
below is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import ResponsiveReactGridLayout from 'react-grid-layout';



const App = () => {
  const layout = [
    { i: 'a', x: 0, y: 0, w: 4, h: 2 },
    { i: 'b', x: 4, y: 0, w: 4, h: 2 },
    { i: 'c', x: 8, y: 0, w: 4, h: 2 },
    { i: 'd', x: 0, y: 2, w: 4, h: 2 }
  ];



  const onDrop = (event: any) => {
    console.log(event);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ResponsiveReactGridLayout
         onDrop={(e) => onDrop(e)} className="layout" layout={layout} cols={12} rowHeight={50} width={1200}>
        <div key="a">a</div>
        <div key="b">b</div>
        <div key="c">c</div>
        <div key="d">d</div>
      </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I onDrop event not work. I cant resize div. I cant get div position and size after drag and drop div.
I confused.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not forget to add the "isDroppable" property to the ResponsiveReactgridlayout component, e.g. `<ResponsiveReactGridLayout isDroppable={true} ...> ... </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>.`

The drop event will be triggered only when an outside component is dropped in the grid. You can find an example inside the demos section of the library. Please use the below link.

https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout/blob/master/test/examples/15-drag-from-outside.jsx